# How to set path for Firefox Binary in Rails when using c9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, firefox, c9.io

For those who don't know, c9 is an online IDE that uses the cloud.  So I’m trying to use FireFox with Watir and the error I’m getting is

> "Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux). Make sure Firefox is
>   installed or set the path manually with
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path="

When I check the file path for FireFox on my PC it’s This PC/Windows(C:)/Program Files/Mozilla FireFox

This is my code which I am using

```
def save
    require 'watir'
    require 'firefox'

    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    @browser.goto "https://kroger.softcoin.com/programs/kroger/digital_coupons/?origin=DigitalCoupons&banner=Smiths#contentBox"

    @browser.div(id: "contentBox").wait_until(&:present?).text

    # Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux). 
    # Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with 
    # Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path=
    # ThisPC:WindowsC:ProgramFiles:MozillaFireFox

    @products = @browser.divs

end
```

Comment: have you used geckodriver

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below code :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:/Program Files/Mozilla FireFox/firefox.exe'
```

Additionally you need to add geckodriver as higher version of firfox do not support without geckodriver

Download geckodriver from below URL :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

You also need to add path of geckodrover as below:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

refer :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Also refer :-

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings

The java code which is working for me is as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\abc\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
```

Comment: Got the error "not a file: "C:/Program Files/Mozilla FireFox/firefox.exe".  Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: have your firefox installed on the same location. Have you check? .. Are you using geckodriver as I mentioned in answer?